# Converting string to real in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I want to convert string representation of real number to real type.
I know that I can do `Real.fromString("5.5")` but it doesn't return real type but real option type which I can't multiply or add with any other real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the value from the option by pattern matching or using one of the functions in the [Option](http://sml.sourceforge.net/Basis/option.html) structure. For example:

```
- val x = Real.fromString("5.5");
> val x = SOME 5.5 : real option
- Option.getOpt(x, 0.0);
> val it = 5.5 : real
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Michael J. Barber's answer, the option type is an algebraic datatype which is either SOME something, or NONE.

Usually, in ML we usually deconstruct algebraic datatypes with pattern matching:

```
case Real.fromString "5.5" of SOME x => x + 1.0
                            | NONE   => 42.0;
```

You could use `getOpt` like Michael J. Barber suggested (you don't actually need the `Option.` since `getOpt` is in the top-level environment), which is a simplified version of the above.

Or, if you are sure that it is going to be a SOME, you could use `valOf` (which will error if it is NONE):

```
- val x = Real.fromString "5.5";
val x = SOME 5.5 : real option
- valOf x;
val it = 5.5 : real
```

or you could pattern-match it away in a `val` (since `val` is also a pattern match, albeit with only one branch):

```
- val SOME x = Real.fromString "5.5";
> val x = 5.5 : real
```